# Comparison of ARIMA and VAR accuracy

Tags: forecasting, arima, model-evaluation, vector-autoregression, model-comparison

Can someone help explaining how to compare a forecast from an ARIMA model and a VAR model.

I have tried calculating MAPE, MSE, RMSE etc. for my VAR forecast, but i simply cannot get it to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: To compare the forecast accuracy of ARIMA and VAR models, I would suggest... calculating MAPE, MSE, RMSE, etc. (If you do not have a prespecified loss function. If you do, calculate only the relevant accuracy measure that is implied by the loss function.) Since this does not work, I would try making it work. If you tell us what you have tried and where you got stuck, perhaps we will be able to help you fix it.

Comment: I have tried to use the accuracy function, but then i get this answer:  
"no applicable method for 'accuracy' applied to an object of class "varprd"".

Also i have tried using this code: accuracy(prd$varresult[[1]]). 

And i have tried calculating MSE with this code: MSE <- mean((as.numeric(var.out)-as.numeric(df_d))^2).